# Is there a way to store cross-browser data using tampermonkey?

Tags: google-chrome, tampermonkey

I'm using one website on a daily basis on my laptop and PC. I don't have access to it's codebase, so I modified it a little to better serve my needs. I'm doing all modifications with TamperMonkey extension for Google Chrome. To store data I'm using cookie variable(but while googling found that it's better to use `GM_setValue()`). To sync it I'm using google doc, where I put contents of that var from PC and copy/paste it on laptop or vice versa.

Maybe there is a better way to sync data with tampermonkey between different browsers?

Comment: Sometimes browser profile synching will work (Alas, there are reported problems with this and TM), but the only practical way is to **use an external file or database.** ...  Google docs can be a good choice and can be automated with various levels of pain. But, the next time I need to do this, I will be using Rdbhost though. I've only run a few tests so far, but it looks to be a much easier way to automate sharing of select data across machines and across browsers.

Comment: @BrockAdams Can you give a piece of code or link to an article? As external file I can use, for example, Dropbox. But how to connect there with TamperMonkey?

Comment: Created temp "answer", now deleted.  May eventually create a proper answer.  No promises. ;)